# Querry Lazy Loading em EF Code First

Tags: entity-framework-6, lazy-loading

É possível criar uma querry lazy loading usando um `DbContext` que está fazendo Eager Loading? Há alguma maneira que eu possa especificar que

```
Company company = db.Comanies.Find(id);
```

este comando não precisa trazer as entidades relacionadas junto dele?

Comment: Qual é a versão do seu EF?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic tenho a 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para desabilitar na `query` especifica faça assim:

```
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
Company company = db.Comanies.Find(id);
```

Comment: Faz sentido, depois experimento para ver se aceito a resposta ;)